# "OSError: Failed to interpret file as a pickle" after saving

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

My code began giving this error after I opened and saved `NEweights.npy`:

```
OSError: Failed to interpret file 'D:\\NeuralNetwork\\NEweights.npy' as a pickle
```

It was working initially before I saved it. Why am I receiving this error only now, and is there any way I can still access the data in `NEweights.npy`? (Just for context, `NEweights.npy` is an array of neural network weights trained via Nesterov Accelerated Gradient. I was testing different NN optimizers.)

I have this code to save the numpy arrays in a npy file:

```py
np.save(f'{path}GDweights.npy', np.array(weights, dtype=object))
```

I have this to access the numpy arrays:

```py
def getWeights(path):
    return np.load(path, allow_pickle=True)

path = 'D:\\NeuralNetwork\\'

inputs, outputs = grab(f'{path}test.csv')
weightsGD = getWeights(f'{path}GDweights.npy')
weightsM = getWeights(f'{path}Mweights.npy')
weightsNE = getWeights(f'{path}NEweights.npy')
weightsNA = getWeights(f'{path}NAweights.npy')
weightsD = getWeights(f'{path}Dweights.npy')
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is raised as an IOError and according to [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html?highlight=numpy%20load) If the input file does not exist or cannot be read, this error is raised.